# CloudFront Not Using SimpleCORS Policy

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

Please note that this issue has reared it's ugly head only within that last 3 or fours days with no modifications to the CloudFront distribution behaviours on our end.

I currently have our distribution (with an S3 Origin) using the SimpleCORS Response headers policy:
[image: Example here]

It seems something has changed recently regarding the SimpleCORS Policy where the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is no longer forwarding the wildcard (*) , or caching the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, resulting with CORS errors all over our affiliate sites.

Has anyone else been experiencing this issue?